# Powershell script to move only files in subfolder to another location ,one subfolder at a time

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am working on a PowerShell script where we need to move files in subfolder to another location ,one subfolder at a time i.e,move files in sub folder1 ,wait for 10 mins then move the files from subfolder 2.
The script moves files in all subfolder

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\PS\"*.HTML -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination E:\work\tst.txt
}
```

Folder structure :

```
Parent folder
  Child1
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
     file3.txt
Child2
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
     file3.txt
Child3
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
     file3.txt
```

Comment: What happens if a file of ChildFolder1 has the same name of a file of ChildFolder2, should it be replaced by the new file or renamed when moved to destination? If renamed, what is the new name?

Comment: There wont be any files with same name .As soon as the file is placed in destination location, the file is uploaded to DB and deleted from destination folder . Hence it wanted files from ChildFolder1 moved first, wait for sometime then move files in next subfolder .wait time i will modify accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to discover each subfolder then:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\PS -Directory |ForEach-Object {
  # move files from this folder to destination
  $_ |Get-ChildItem -File |Move-Item -Destination E:\work\ -Force

  # wait 10 minutes
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
}
```